# ConcurrentHashMap getting emptied?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I have a service class in my application in which i am declaring a map like this -

```
Map<String, Boolean> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>([:])
```

I am using below function to initialise the map. This method is called only once when we start the application(during seeding).-

```
void addValue(Boolean val) {
    myMap.put("Key", val)
}
```

When i try to print the map, once application is up, it works fine and prints value as expected. But if i change something in this class, save my changes, and refresh the page, the map is getting emptied. It's printing as **[:]**. It gives null pointer exception in my application. I can't understand why is this happening.

Comment: what exactly did you expect when you do class reloading in dev-mode?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your map is being emptied is because changes to your class is causing the service to be recompiled and a new instance created.

You don't specify how "seeding" your map is happening in your application, but that is not being done when the new instance of your service is created.